# Codeigniter 404 Page Not Found for no reason

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I tried to run this project locally: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lp4nL4eOn_19yKAc1RV0GoY3f-y9-9VD

However when I log-in with user: `laura` and password: `laura123`, I'm getting this error:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

I tried to create a `.htaccess` file but it did not help, the project runs normally on my coworker's laptops. It's supposed to show: *http://localhost/tenis.dev/index.php/arbitros*.

Can you help me?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try posting the code in the question.

Comment: If you claim its working on your coworkers Laptops and not on your system - what is the difference between them? Something aint the same...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to load up your site and have a play with it. Out of the box, I can confirm your error.

It would appear that you are running on a Linux box...

You need to learn to use your browsers developer tools and look in the console... It was throwing up errors...

Long story short...

In your views/templates/public.php

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js//App.js')?>"></script>
```

In your assets/js/ folder you have app.js.

The case of filenames in a Linux system is very important i.e they must match...

So...
The line above needs to be altered to

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/app.js')?>"></script>
```

Note: Also removed the extra / you had after `assets/js//` Keep an eye on that kind of thing as it's "untidy"...

If you still have issues, I had to make the additional changes to make it work... but these won't really affect you...

$config['base_url'] - I had to change it of course.

In the app.js file I had to alter the siteUrl to match my setup.
Oh and a small change in the database config file...

So after the changes to the app.js link it will work.
It breaks again if I put it back to what you have.

Have fun!

Comment: Yea linux is a pain in the butt when it comes to paths

Comment: Or you get too used to the sloppiness of Windows :)

Comment: Thank you all for the answer, all we run our apps on windows, and all I have in my PC is Xampp and Sublime, Yesterday at night we tried to run it on University's PCs but we had the same problem.

Then I changed what @Timbrownlaw recommend, and nothing has changed.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dEOfPRpt2XEhcM-l8_-RzSDKIfWuFY_e
The console does not show errors.

Comment: Ok, but what happens when you just use the URL localhost/tenis.dev - what shows in the console then. The thing is - I took your code and it produced the error you are seeing. Then I debugged it, using your code, database etc and got it working. So please inspect localhost/tenis.dev in the console - what do you get.